# How to get Full Calendar event id onClick using Laravel and Vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar

When a User clicks on an event, I want to show a Modal with the Interview data for that specific id inside of it. All of the events, are interviews stored in a table called interviews.

For some reason in my controller, it's not able to find any id using the find method.
And when I click on an event, no matter which one I click on, it returns an array with all of the event objects for that user. How can I get the event id when clicking on a single event?

Here is a screenshot.
[image]

I'm using the Full Calendar Vue Component from the docs.
The `$id` in the `find` method is null and not able to find anything for some reason.

----------- UPDATED -----------

CandidateCalendarController.php:

```
public function index() {

        $interviews = Interview::where('candidate_user_id', auth::user()->id)->get();

        return Response::json(array(
            'events' => $interviews,
        ), 200);

    }

    public function show($id) {

        $interview = Interview::find($id);

        return Response::json(array(
            'interview' => $interview,
        ), 200);

    }
```

router.js:

```
{
    path: '/employer/calendar',
    name: 'employer-calendar-index',
    component: CalendarIndex,
    meta: {
        breadcrumb: 'My Calendar',
        requiresAuthEmployer: true,
        // employerHasPaid: true
    },
},

{
    path: '/employer/calendar/:interviewId/show',
    name: 'employer-calendar-show',
    component: CalendarIndex,
    meta: {
        breadcrumb: 'My Calendar',
        requiresAuthEmployer: true,
        // employerHasPaid: true
    },
}
```

CandidateCalendar.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-container fluid>
            <b-row>
                <b-col>
                <FullCalendar
                    :plugins="calendarPlugins"
                    :header="{
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                        }"
                    :events="events"
                    @eventClick="showEvent"
                />
                </b-col>
                <b-modal ref="eventModal" id="modal-1" title="Update Profile" hide-footer>

                    {{this.interview}}

                </b-modal>
            </b-row>
        </b-container>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
    import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
    import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
    import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
    import listPlugin from "@fullcalendar/list";
    import * as candidateInterviewService from '../services/candidate_interview_service.js';

    export default {
        components: {
            FullCalendar
        },
        data() {
            return {
                calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
                events: [],
                interview: []
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.getEvents();
        },
        methods: {

            getEvents: async function() {
                const response = await candidateInterviewService.loadInterviews();
                this.events = response.data.events;
            },

            showEvent: async function() {
                const interviewId = this.$route.params.interviewId;
                // this.$refs.eventModal.show();
                const response = await candidateInterviewService.loadInterview(interviewId);
                console.log(response);
                this.interview = response.data.interview;
            }

        },
    };
</script>

<style>
    @import "~@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
    @import "~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
    @import "~@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";

    .fc-title, .fc-content {
        color: white;
    }

    .fc-unthemed {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```

api.php:

```
Route::get('/candidate/calendar', 'CandidateCalendarController@index')->name('candidate.calendar.index');
    Route::get('/candidate/calendar/{calendarId}/show', 'CandidateCalendarController@show')->name('candidate.calendar.show');
```

candidate_interview_service.js:

```
export function loadInterviews(data) {
    return http().get('/candidate/calendar');
}

export function loadInterview(interviewId) {
    return http().get(`/candidate/calendar/${interviewId}/show`);
}
```

After I click an event and `console.log(response)`, it still says undefined in the url. See screenshot.
[image]

Comment: `const response = await candidateInterviewService.loadInterview()` ...you aren't passing any ID into the method here. Same with `const response = await candidateInterviewService.loadInterviews();`, even though those methods accept ID (and data in one case as well). So it's unclear why you expect ID not to be null - your code clearly never supplies it. Although I can't see actually how your PHP show() method is being triggered? Is that linked to your URL routes somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I copied some older code into my question. I have now updated all of my code in my original post. I am now trying to pass ```interviewId``` into the show method in api.php, in router.js and in candidate_interview_service.js. Please see above updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to get the id like this and make everything work.
I changed the showEvent async function in CandidateCalendar.vue to this:

```
showEvent: async function(arg) {
    const { id } = this.events.find(
        event => event.id === +arg.event.id
    );
    const response = await candidateInterviewService.loadInterview(id);
    this.interview = response.data.interview;
    this.$refs.eventModal.show();
},
```